# In PostgreSQL, I'm performing an UPSERT on 1000 rows, I'm using ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING, if 1 row fails, do the other 999 get inserted?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I'm trying to understand how the ON CONFLICT clause works. What I want, is if an insert fails for any reason, I want it to do nothing with the row, but continue processing the other items in the bulk insert.

Here's my scenario. I'm building a bulk insert query, with 1000 rows to be inserted. Currently, my query has:

```
INSERT INTO table (...,...,...) 
VALUES (...,...,...),(...,null..,...), (998 more) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT primary_key DO NOTHING
```

What I want to know is can I do this:

```
INSERT INTO table (...,...,...) VALUES (...,...,...),(...,null..,...), (998 more) 
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

This would effectively take any conflict inserting a row (in my case a null constraint on a column) and just not insert it. I need to ensure that if there is 1 conflict for one row, that the other 999 rows will still be inserted.

**UPDATE:** here's a demo showing the issue I'm encountering: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=8947dbcd38e9136531b907d3c745c0f5

**UPDATE 2:** It looks like when you pass null values, it fails the entire bulk insert process.

**FINAL UPDATE:** Accepted the first answer because of that cool demo link - which helped me realize (and in the comments) that `null` isn't captured, so I just need to change my table structure and rely on the primary key... so when duplicate nulls are added, the pkey constraint gets triggered. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Easy solution: Try it and find out?

Comment: haha - yeah that's what I was hoping to find out because it isn't clear if you can do that in the documentation @tadman

Comment: If you've got a schema and some example queries the behaviour should be pretty obvious. If this is anything like MySQL's `INSERT IGNORE` then the answer is probably "yes".

Comment: Just did a test (as you suggested @tadman) because I'm impatient ;-). Expected insert is 9122, amount inserted was 8122. So it appears that doing ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING, fails the entire bulk insert, not just the offending row. Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: ON CONFLICT can only ignore constraint violations for unique constraints. It will not ignore any other constraint violation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All rows for which there is no conflict will be inserted, and the conflicting row will be ignored.

Consider **[this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ba4af850d6f602b242a2a7d4076ce003)**:

```
-- create the table and insert a record with id 1
create table t (id int primary key, info text);
insert into t values (1, 'old');
-- 1 rows affected

-- attempt to insert 5 'new' records with ids 1 .. 5
insert into t 
select n, 'new' from generate_series(1, 5) as n(n) on conflict do nothing;
-- 4 rows affected

-- check the results
select * from t;
```

```
id | info
-: | :---
 1 | old 
 2 | new 
 3 | new 
 4 | new 
 5 | new
```

Comment: That's really interesting - I just ran a test and the opposite thing happened! @GMB I'll take a look at that demo....

Comment: check out this demo, it shows my use case better: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=8947dbcd38e9136531b907d3c745c0f5

Comment: ...fixed link in comment too

Comment: @tvpmb: the query in your fiddlde has errors. (1) `insert ... select (1, 1), (2, 2) ...` should be `insert ... values (1, 1), (2, 2)...` (2) you are assigning a `null` value to non-nullable column `value` for id `4`).

Comment: yes sorry, I fixed the demo. That's exactly my issue. I'm getting a ```null``` value and the column constraint doesn't allow me to insert, and it fails the whole bulk insert. Check the updated link.

Comment: I think the issue is now just specifically when I get null values the entire bulk insert fails. Check out the updated link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=8947dbcd38e9136531b907d3c745c0f5

Comment: @tvpmb: I don't know about a built-in way to avoid that in Postgres. `ON CONFLICT` is meant for key constraints, not null constraints. You need to check your data for `null`s before you `insert`.